# SQL:Select columns based on rows of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

How do I create a sql select statement where the select column names are values in rows of another table (I am using postgresql)? I have a language table with language codes:

```
language
========
id    code  name
-------------------
1     en    English
2     fr    French
3     it    Italian

country
=======
id    en    fr    it   other_columns
------------------------------------
1     ...
2     ...
```

I want to select the id and all the language columns from the country table and they are listed in the language table. Something like:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT code FROM language) FROM country
```

so I effectively end up with:

```
SELECT id, en, fr, it from country
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a "pivot" or "crosstab" and is something SQL is notoriously bad for. PostgreSQL offers an extension that helps a bit, though it's not beautiful to use - take a look at the [`crosstab` function in the `tablefunc` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html).

A search for the [crosstab](/questions/tagged/crosstab) or [pivot](/questions/tagged/pivot) tags along with the [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) tag will find you more. Eg:

- [crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crosstab+postgresql)
- [pivot questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot+postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. The following line gives you the SQL you are looking for. Perhaps PL/pgSQL's EXECUTE could actually run it for you.

```
SELECT 'SELECT id, ' 
    || (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(code),', ') FROM LANGUAGE) 
    || 'FROM country';
```

Some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE country (id integer, en text, fr text, it text, es text, de text);
INSERT INTO country (id, en, fr, it, es, de) 
VALUES (1, 'Hello', 'Bonjour', 'Buon giorno', 'Buenas dias', 'Guten Tag');

CREATE TABLE language (id integer, code text, name text);
INSERT INTO language (id, code, name) 
VALUES (1, 'en', 'English'), (2, 'fr', 'French'), (3, 'it', 'Italian');
```